# Rewrite dynamically calculation to avoid numpy IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I am trying to calculate this:`(x[z + 1] - x[z])`

x has the shape of `(31, )` and z has the shape of `(10000, )`. z being indexes from 0 to 30.

The error I think comes from this part: `x[z + 1]` where it fails when it exceeds the length of the shape `(31, )`

I have tried to run this in a while loop with the length of x and a counter but this didn't work.

How can I rewrite this to avoid this IndexError of "out of bounds"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] of the code you tried.

Comment: It appears that you already understand the problem.  The solution depends on why you are computing `x[z + 1] - x[z]`, and what you think *should* happen when `z` is 30.

Comment: Commonly when we want sequential differences we use `x[1:] - x[:-1]`.  That is  30 terms starting with the 2nd minus 30 terms except the last.  That gives the `z+1/z` offset.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know np.diff:

```
np.diff(x)
```

?

If you want to do it in a clumsy way, you could use slicing:

```
x[1:] - x[:len(x)-1]
```

, but I don't know why you would want to do that :-)